# prove by induction that the sum of first nth triangular numbers is the nth tetrahedral number for all n in z

Tags: induction, triangles

prove by induction that the sum of first nth triangular numbers is the nth tetrahedral number for all n $\epsilon Z^+$

I know that by induction for triangular numbers we get

f(n) = 1+ 2+3....+n = n(n+1)\2

and if n =1 then we get 1(2)\ 2 = 1 true

we let n = k we get (k + 1)(k + 1 + 1)/2

im not sure how to tie this into tetrahedral numbers can someone explain?

Comment: How have you defined tetrahedral numbers? If these are just the number of balls used to build a tetrahedron with side length $n$, then consider cutting your tetrahedron in horizontal slices. Every slice is a triangle and hence, the number of balls of the slice is a triangular number.

Comment: Usually the tetrahedral numbers are defined as the sum of the triangular numbers.  Then the challenge is to prove a formula for the tetrahedral numbers.  What formula do you have for the tetrahedral numbers?  Wouldn't it be nice to supply that with your question?

Comment: 1/6n(n+1)(n+2) is the formula